# Almacenar registros traídos de una BD

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net, vb6

Tengo un sistema hecho en VisualBasic el cual estoy pasando a C#, utiliza RECORDSET para almacenar los registros de una consulta para despues llamar esos datos almacenados y utlizarlos en el resto del sistema. Por ejemplo, aqui debajo estoy poniendo como es la declaracion, como hace la consulta y posteriormente como hace uso de los datos

```vb
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RsDatos As ADODB.Recordset


Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.Open "SELECT Tabla.PersonaId AS ID, Tabla.PNombre AS NOMBRE, Tabla.PAPaterno AS PATERNO, Tabla.PAMaterno AS MATERNO FROM Tabla"

'FUNCION
Private sub Mostrar()

lblID = RsDatos("ID")
lblNombre = RsDatos("NOMBRE")
lblPaterno = RsDatos("PATERNO")
lblMaterno = RsDatos("MATERNO")
```

O por ejemplo para otra consulta utiliza el dato ya almacenado

```
"SELECT Fecha AS FECHA From Tabla2 WHERE Id = " & RsDatos("ID") &"
```

Entonces quisiera saber como se puede almacenar los registros de una consulta para después usarlos, pero en c#. ¿Existe alguna libreria o una propiedad que haga eso?

Comment: Una buena opción sería usar [expresiones lambda](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), la cual tiene multiples métodos para interactuar con la BD

Comment: Puedes utilizar un DataSet

Comment: Hace mucho no uso DataSet, pero no seria lo mismo colocar tu consulta en una List<Tabla2>  tabla2 = new List<Tabla2>(); previamente creas tu clase con las propiedades que tiene la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

sería algo equivalente en c# llamando un datareader y que recupera la lectura de todos tus registros de la tabla  "TABLA"

pero creo que el control label no seria el indicado para recuperar los datos ya que se encontraría en un ciclo while; para esto tomaría un datagridview o control parecido o equivalente en asp.net para realizar la convertir de vb 6 a c# .net

```
   public void mostrar()
{
string connectionString = "server=TU SERVIDOR DE BD; user ID=NOMBREUSUARIO"; Password= TUPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=TUNOMBREBD";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Tabla.PersonaId AS ID, Tabla.PNombre AS NOMBRE, Tabla.PAPaterno AS PATERNO, Tabla.PAMaterno AS MATERNO FROM Tabla", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                lblID.Text  = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")).toString();
                lblNombre  = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NOMBRE")).toString();;
                lblPaterno = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("PATERNO")).toString();
                lblMaterno = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MATERNO")).toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```